# How to reference project with nuget

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, projects-and-solutions

I am trying to wrap extra functionality around `json.net` (`Newtonsoft.Json` nuget) into class library `Json`:

[image]

The problem: adding `Json` reference to `Test` doesn't add references to nuget auto-magically. The idea is to add reference to `Json` in multiple solutions afterwards. But I am only able to access `Json` types, `Json.net` namespaces aren't available.

Point is: I reference `Json`, reference to `Json` is added, `json.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` get copied on build, but `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` **is not referenced automatically**.

I can solve the problem manually by: 1) adding references to all dlls referenced in `Json` into `Test` 2) adding nuget into `Test`. But I don't like either of them.

My question: what is the *correct* way to do what I want? Perhaps my idea of wrapping `json.net` is wrong? And nugets aren't designed to be used like this...

Comment: Why do you want to add Newtonsoft.Json dll to your Test project ? If you are trying to create a wrapper around Newtonsoft.Json dll, you shouldn't have the need to refer the parent dll otherwise it is not a wrapper anyways.

Comment: Are you actually wrapping it or just extending it? As Dilip said above, if you are wrapping it, you should be exposing everything you need from your Json dll.  If you are extending it, you would need to add references to the Nuget package in each project.  There is nothing wrong with referencing it in both places.

Comment: Good point. `Json` add some functionality, but I still need `json.net` types in `Test`, e.g. attributes `JsonPropertyAttribute`. The *true wrapper* would hide them, I don't really want that. I want `json.net` namespaces to be available, because anyway adding `json` as reference will cause `json.dll` **and** `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to be copied into `Test\Bin`. My question is rather why adding reference to `Json` project doesn't add reference to its nugets? **Somehow** `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is get copied, but it's not referenced. This is wrong and feels stupid, unless I don't know something.

Comment: @bhmahler, adding nuget to each project in addition to referencing `Json` (which is fully sufficient to reference alone) feels wrong. Multiple unnecessary copies of same thing everywhere, including output folder of every project referencing `json`.

Comment: They will both reference the json.net library but in the end you will only have a single copy of the json.net dll being referenced by each project. If the projects are independent of each other than you would have multiple copies but this is expected as each packaged project would need it. It should also be using a single nuget packages folder for your solution and adding the additional reference to the package will just link the test project to the existing dll in that folder.

Comment: @bhmahler, I was talking about multiple solutions (containing projects). How do I organize "single nuget packages folder for your solution" ? Currently nuget is per project. Removing nuget from `Json` project (and referencing it instead) makes sense, at least for `Json` solution (this way both `Test` and `Json` project will reference single instance of nuget).

Comment: That is correct, nuget is per project, but your solution will use a single packages folder and store all packages for projects in the solution in that single folder.  Unfortunately, since you need this dll referenced in each project, you will need to add the package or manually link the dll to the project.  The problem with manual linking is that if you update the Nuget package, the reference will be broken.