# Force build/ deploy to include assembly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deployment, dependencies, continuous-integration

I ran into the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033193/entity-framework-provider-type-could-not-be-loaded) where the build server didn't see my EF assembly because EF was only in my data project, so it didn't include it in my release... even though it was necessary.  The proposed solutions were to make a reference in my main project.

Well, I really don't want to do that... I don't want my main project knowing anything about EF; it shouldn't care where or how the data is getting to it.  Is there a way to force the builder/ deployer to include a specific assembly, I don't care if you don't think it's necessary, just do it anyway?

Comment: Problem to [reference project with dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36477275/1997232)? Well, I started using [shared projects](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/) (instead of class libraries) and referencing every dependency in main project. Life is a beach and then you marry one.

Comment: That won't work at all in a SOA-based environment, and continuous integration would be a nightmare.  IMPO, That's an even worse workaround than referencing the assembly.